# Slack: Updating the same image URL that changes daily to show all the changes

Tags: slack

I have a Slack channel that I send an image to on a daily basis from a third party service.

The issue is that they do not change the image url so it is always:

```
http://website.com/image.url
```

even though the image itself changes, as in it shows different information.

In Slack it recognises the URL and changes all the previous days image to match today.

I tried adding a query to the end of the image eg:

```
http://website.com/image.url?timestamp=12345678
```

but Slack is clever enough to ignore that.

Does anybody know of a way to get around this other than make a copy of the image and save it as a different URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Slack probably [caches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60303414/10940584) the image, either locally on your device or on their servers (the former seems more likely). You might want to try fully closing and reopening Slack if you haven't already. Several [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60297736/10940584) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61750580/10940584) describe different behavior (i.e., Slack dynamically retrieving the image so that it is updated to reflect the newest version), so this may be due to something they have changed or a temporary issue on their end. I would try refreshing and/or logging out and back in again, then re-uploading the image if this doesn't work.